# Embedding a Plotly graph to Java GUI

Tags: java, python, browser, plotly

I have a interactive plotly graph which I wish to put in to a Java GUI.

I am using swing for the Java GUI.

the plotly functions and displays correctly on Chrome, but not on Java swing components.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start plotly as a seperated web service and call it via embedded browser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31002668)